# String formatting to percentage and how to handle the null?

Tags: c#, asp.net, string, gridview, formatting

Hello I have a bound field in gridview, which I am formating it to show as a percentage. Everything works good, but when the column have null values it is throwing error. Could yo please let me know a way to address the null values.

```
    <asp:BoundField DataField="ip_per" SortExpression="ip_per" DataFormatString="{0.0%}" />
```

Comment: What type is the field? What nulls should be threaten as? Zeros?

Comment: it is a decimal. While displaying I want to show empty string for null values

Comment: `<asp:BoundField NullDisplayText="" />` but am not so sure

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may set  `NullDisplayText`.

```
 <asp:BoundField DataField="ip_per" 
                 SortExpression="ip_per"
                 NullDisplayText=""
                 DataFormatString="{0.0%}" />
```